# Configure Brackets Beautify extension to add new line before curly braces

Tags: code-formatting, adobe-brackets, curly-braces

I'm using [Brackets Beautify](https://github.com/brackets-beautify/brackets-beautify) extension, and having an issue while beautifying my code.

Let's say I have this code:

```
function test(arg1, arg2)
{
    var a = arg1 + arg2;
    return a;
}

var object = 
{
    "some" : 123,
    "some2" : 13123
}
```

When I click Ctrl + Alt + B in order to beautify my code, the function above will look like this:

```
function test(arg1, arg2) {
    var a = arg1 + arg2;
    return a;
}

var object = {
    "some": 123,
    "some2": 13123
}
```

But I want it to keep look like the first one (where the curly braces are in new line), because it's more readable for me.

I tried searching for solution, but no success.

BTW, I'm talking about JavaScript. The PHP code is OK.

Any ideas?

---

Sorry for any English mistakes, I'm not a native speaker.

**EDIT:** Found a partial solution. I changed "**brace_style**" to "**expand**" in "**default.jsbeautifyrc**" file (somehow it didn't work while doing this in the "**.jsbeautifyrc**" file).

Anyway, it still doesn't work for arrays and objects.

**EDIT 2:** Just noticed that it happens also in CSS code.

Answer (score 1):

I've been running into the same situation.

I tweaked my css beautifier code locally to get around it.

It's the *beautify-css.js* file located in the *Third Party* folder of your extension installation directory.

On my Elementary OS it's here :

```
~/.config/Brackets/extensions/user/brackets-beautify-2.4.0/thirdparty/beautify-css.js
```

Change the lines of code, reload Brackets, and it's done.

Here are my tweaks (base on brackets-beautify-2.4.0) :

The first two are in the print["{"] method. This function becomes :

```
 print["{"] = function(ch) {
        print.newLine(); //instead of print.singleSpace(); 
        indent();//since indent removed at 383
        output.push(ch);
        print.newLine();
    };
```

This change consists in :

- l 255 `print.singleSpace();` becomes `print.newLine();`
- l 256 becomes a new line and contains `indent();`

Then go to line 383 and comment it.

- l 383 `indent();` is removed

Adding a real *brace-style* option for CSS would be a more elegant solution.

This aims to help anyone looking for a quick fix to make it work locally.

Comment: I'm on Windows and the code is pretty different, I can't even find this code in my file.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `.jsbeautifyrc` with the following content achieves the desired brace placement for JS:

```
{
    "js": {
        "brace_style": "expand"
    }
}
```

For CSS, this option is not (yet) supported by the underlying library.

The configuration file should be in the root folder of your project (the folder you open in Brackets). That way you can check it into version control so every contributor has the same formatting settings.

If you want the same settings globally, you *could* change the `default.jsbeautifyrc` file in the extension folder, but it would be reverted on update.

Comment: where should i create this file on windows? i tried:
c:/users/userName,
C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\Brackets\extensions\user\brackets-beautify,
C:\Users\Evyatar\AppData\Roaming\Brackets\

Nothing worked :(

Comment: In the root of the project you have opened in Brackets. That way you can have different configurations for each of your projects.

Comment: But I want to use the same configuration for all of my projects.

Comment: You could change the global default, but it would be reverted on extension update (see updated answer).

Comment: I'm using CodeMix for Eclipse and trying so doesn't work. ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

After reading the answer of @redpanda, I tried changing the code myself.

I changed some lines in the `beautify-css.js` file, which is located in windows inside `C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\Brackets\extensions\user\brackets-beautify\thirdparty` directory.

This is my solution:

Go to line `463` in `beautify-css.js` file, and change it from this:

```
 indent();
 output.space_before_token = true;
 print_string(ch);

 if (!eatWhitespace(true)) {
      output.add_new_line();
 }
```

To this:

```
  //indent(); // removed, we will indent later
  output.space_before_token = true;
  output.add_new_line(); // added, in order to add new line before '{'
  print_string(ch);

  if (!eatWhitespace(true)) 
  {
      output.add_new_line();
  }
  indent(); //added, in order to indent, since we removed it before
```

Of course this is a temporary solution, and i hope that real brace-style option will be added.

Comment: You should consider making a Pull Request [here](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify) to add the feature.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for css (beautify version 2.10.0)

> File beautify-css.js (Path: ~\AppData\Roaming\Brackets\extensions\user\brackets-beautify\thirdparty)

Line ~1411

> Find "else if (this._ch === '#' && this._input.peek() === '{')"

Sample code

```
} else if (this._ch === '#' && this._input.peek() === '{') {
  this.preserveSingleSpace(isAfterSpace);
  this.print_string(this._ch + this.eatString('}'));
} else if (this._ch === '{') {
  if (insidePropertyValue) {
//this._output.add_new_line();
    insidePropertyValue = false;
    this.outdent();
  }
  this.indent();
  this.__add_space_before_token();
  //this._output.space_before_token = true;
  this.print_string(this._ch);
```

Change to

```
} else if (this._ch === '#' && this._input.peek() === '{') {
  this.preserveSingleSpace(isAfterSpace);
  this.print_string(this._ch + this.eatString('}'));
} else if (this._ch === '{') {
  if (insidePropertyValue) {
    insidePropertyValue = false;
    this.outdent();
  }
  this.print_string('\n');  // this line has been changed
  this.outdent();           // this line has been changed
  this.print_string(this._ch);
  this.indent();            // this line has been changed
```